# Cannot make Cross-origin resource sharing request using jquery AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

i am Trying to upload image to some **External URL**. I am getting **Cross-Origin Request Blocked** in the console. My response contains complete JSON data.

I have got a form with enctype="multipart/form-data". And this is my ajax

```
 $.ajax({
    url: 'externalURL/image/upload'
    type: 'POST',                               
    cache: false,
    processData:false,
    crossDomain: true,                                                          
    dataType : 'jsonp', 
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
    data: $("#multiform").serialize(),  
    beforeSend: function (xhr)
    { 
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept","text/json");
    },
    error: function (xhr, status) {
        alert(status);
    },
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);  
    }
});
```

I am getting error alert , when i try to upload.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work

Comment: IE Cross origin request is not allowed by default and has to be turned on at the server alternativly there is solutions like JSONP but these workarounds is very limited and troublesome.